# How to correctly (syntax) write this line Vue

Tags: vue.js, syntax

What is the correct syntax for this line Vue:

```html
<iframe src="/'product.id'/file.php' " frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The line came to the form:

```html
<iframe src="/5/file.php">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```html
<iframe :src="`/${product.id}/file.php`" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: and how to write this line correctly inside the script? `export default {
metaInfo: {
      title: {product.name} Wallpaper`

Comment: Create a new question and I will answer it. This way other epople can benefit from it too :)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629685/how-write-this-line-vue/59629744?noredirect=1#comment105421720_59629744]