# How to use a Vue variable in metaInfo?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, syntax, vue-meta

What is the correct syntax for this line Vue inside the script:

```
export default {
metaInfo: {
      title: "{product.name} wallpaper",
```

The line came to the form:

```
title: "Space wallpaper",
```

`product.name` I get it  in api:

```
mounted() 
{ 
let vm = this
vm.getProducts(); 

},
methods: {
getProducts() {
                let vm = this
                axios.get('/api/products')
                    .then(function(response) {
                        vm.products = response.data.data  
                    })
```

Comment: Are you looking to build a string based on a property? Assuming product is a property, would something like this get you closer:

    export default {
        metaInfo: {
            : this.product.name + ' wallpaper',

Comment: @JonE product.name I get it in api. added in the question.

Comment: I still don't see "product" anywhere.  Is product the current item in a loop in the template?   As much code as possible would make it easier for someone to help.  That said, the script is just javascript, so if you're building a string, use string concatenation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) use backticks and a dollar sign before the braces, e.g.:

```
title: `${product.name} wallpaper`
```

To use reactive variables in the `metaInfo` as part of a function, the [Vue Meta docs](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/guide/caveats.html#reactive-variables-in-template-functions) says that you can make `metaInfo` a function and assign the reactive variable to a local variable before returning the data. For example:

```
metaInfo() {
      const product = this.product;
      return {
          title: `${product.name} wallpaper`
      }
}
```

One of the contributors to Vue Meta explained why you need to do it this way [here](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/issues/322#issuecomment-466317878).

Comment: this not work. this code inside tags <script></script>

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? Could it be that your browser doesn't [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals) template literals yet?

Comment: this code is not in the <template></template> tags. the browser is fine

Comment: @algebra I added some info I found in the docs now. Hope that works for you.

Comment: It saved my day. Thanks @DMalan. 
I was using metaInfo as property. After I changed it to method the problem solved.